# xpath not operator and multiple select

Tags: python, xpath

```
for link in hxs.select("//a[contains(@href,'/women-')]"):
    if ('.a[notcontains(@href,"/women-shoes")]'):
        self.log("LINKS2 :: %s" % attribute::href())
```

The first statement is selecting all the hyperlinks which contain `/women-` in their url. Basically I want to select all links which have `/women-` in their url but not `/women-shoes`.

1. How can I put that condition in the `for` loop itself. I am looking for the correct usage of `not` operator in the loop condition. Also,
2. If I want to do something like select all links with `/women-` in their url and then in the if condition I want to check if the link doesn't have `/women-shoes` in the url, how do I do that?

Comment: It's generally a good idea to post a sample of the data you want to process and what you want to get out of it.

Comment: The data looks something like <a class="" href="/women-shoes/fsdfdsfsd....">abc</a> <a class="" href="/women-skate/fdsfds..">pqr</a>

Comment: If you're adding detail to the question, like providing a sample. Please edit the question instead of putting it in comments. Have a read of: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not filter within your query?

```py
queryStr = "//a[contains(@href,'/women-') and not(contains(@href,'/women-shoes'))]"
for link in hxs.select(queryStr):
    self.log("LINKS2 :: %s" % attribute::href())
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be more optimized as it will see first url not contains /women-shoes and then check whether it contains /women- :

```
queryStr = "//a[not(contains(@href,'/women-shoes')) and contains(@href,'/women-') ]
```